# INSERT INTO new table - all inserts start in same row

Tags: mysql

Good day.

I am trying to insert multiple "select query results" in a new table (tblTEST).

I wish, that every select query result "populates" the corresponding column in tblTEST.

```
INSERT INTO tblTEST (SkuNo)
SELECT 
a.SKU_NO FROM tbl0SKU_NO a 
INNER JOIN tbl1SKUS b ON a.SKU_NOID=b.SkuNo
;

INSERT INTO tblTEST (Brand)
SELECT
c.Brand FROM tbl0Brands c
INNER JOIN tbl1SKUS d ON c.BrandID=d.Brand
;

INSERT INTO tblTEST (ProductName)
SELECT
e.ProductName FROM tbl0ProductNames e
INNER JOIN tbl1SKUS f ON e.ProductNameID=f.ProductName
;
```

Above pasted code, does insert data in tblTEST, BUT, it does it in such a manner that it fills the values for the first column (SKUNo), and all the other rows in the table are "null".  After the values for first column are inserted, then the values for the second column (Brand) are inserted and again the other rows in the table are NULL, so on till the end.

Please see picture for explanation:
[image: Fig.1:Insert into tblTEST_result]

So, how, do I "insert into new table", so that every insert begins at row 1?
(I don't know if the question is clear, i apologize for that)
Number of rows for each "select query" are the same.

Should I use an UPDATE after the first INSERT INTO?

```
INSERT INTO tblTEST (SkuNo)
    SELECT 
    a.SKU_NO FROM tbl0SKU_NO a 
    INNER JOIN tbl1SKUS b ON a.SKU_NOID=b.SkuNo
    ;
    
    **UPDATE** tblTEST (Brand)
    SELECT
    c.Brand FROM tbl0Brands c
    INNER JOIN tbl1SKUS d ON c.BrandID=d.Brand
    ;
```

If so, what would the syntax be, for the UPDATE?

Other suggestions for formatting "INSERT INTO" would be helpful.

I googled for the answer but, to be quite frank, I don't know what/how to search.

Comment: Build a SELECT statement that has all three columns populated just the way you like. Then turn that into an INSERT statement. Use a JOIN to join the tables together. (In other words, don't worry about the INSERT. Build a SELECT to get the exact result set that you want to build your new table, then toss the INSERT on to the front of that).

Comment: Why you don't use one INSERT statement for all fields?

Comment: i don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do insert with joining other tables with tbl1SKUS

```
INSERT INTO tblTEST (SkuNo,Brand,ProductName )
SELECT 
a.SKU_NO,c.Brand, e.ProductName FROM tbl1SKUS b
INNER JOIN tbl0SKU_NO a ON a.SKU_NOID=b.SkuNo,
INNER JOIN tbl0Brands c ON c.BrandID=b.Brand,
INNER JOIN tbl0ProductNames e ON e.ProductNameID=b.ProductName
```

Comment: Missed productName while copy paste, I formatted your query only, but if you use a, b, c, d on order it will be easy to understand

Answer (score 2):

How about a three way join:

```
INSERT INTO tblTEST (SkuNo, Brand, ProductName)
SELECT 
    b.SKU_NO,
    c.Brand,
    d.ProductName
FROM tbl1SKUS a
INNER JOIN tbl0SKU_NO b
    ON b.SKU_NOID = a.SkuNo
INNER JOIN tbl0Brands c
    ON c.BrandID = a.Brand
INNER JOIN tbl0ProductNames d
    ON d.ProductNameID = a.ProductName
```

If you want to insert a new row in SQL, you generally would want to include all information in that single insert statement.  Using a join between all your tables accomplishes that.  If you did need to modify a record after inserting it, you would have to use update.  But update probably isn't the way to go for what you want here.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

I have to admit it is easier to view code with "ones own" table names and such.